# Can't get dropdown to appear after creating entity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core, data-annotations, datalist

I just wanted to be able for a user to select from a dropdown if their id number was a ssn or ein.

I created a Farm entity and I wanted the user to select from a dropdown using Datalist whether or not it was an EIN or SSN so I created a TPINType (taxpayer id # type) Entity and added it to AppConstants and to the Database and I am not sure if I am missing a data annotation or something but I can't get it to even populate the TPINType on the screen where someone would add their farm

```
    [UIHint("SelectListModel")]
    [DataMember]
    [Display(AutoGenerateField = false, Name = "TPIN Type")]
    public virtual TPINType TPINType { get; set; }
```

Comment: Show your relevant view markup.

Comment: what if I am using a ViewModel?

Comment: You already have shown your ViewModel code, we can't do much with what is given.

Comment: you should use enum class for that

Comment: I figured it out, I was missing an Object.cshtml file in our Shared/EditorTemplates, once I copied and pasted that file from another app everything rendered correctly.